# MySQL: optimize pagination queries

Tags: mysql, performance, pagination

I found an article speak about MySQL performance tips, and here is one of their tips:

> MySQL performance tip No. 7: Watch out for pagination queries
>
> On the query side, instead of using LIMIT with offset, you can select
> one more row than you need, and when the user clicks the "next page"
> link, you can designate that final row as the starting point for the
> next set of results. For example, if the user viewed a page with rows
> 101 through 120, you would select row 121 as well; to render the next
> page, you'd query the server for rows greater than or equal to 121,
> limit 21.
>
> URL: http://www.infoworld.com/article/2616674/database-administration/10-essential-performance-tips-for-mysql.html?page=2

My Question is: Do this really help in pagination queries?

Comment: `[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]` ... so what is the implication, that you do the same thing except subtract one from `offset` ?

Comment: `limit with offset` vs `Greater than specific id with limit` ?

Comment: Depends on your sort (presentation) and indexes. Which the indexes would be the same anyway under this theory --> you presentation is prob not always useful by `id` but rather some other strategy. Like by some date, a join, alpha. Depends what you are doing.

Comment: @mwafi: I personally think it's pretty naive to assume that all identifiers would always be a continuous sequence.

Comment: @jakubwrona The excerpt above seems fine if the page size is 21. But sure, there are id gaps all over the place, but for page sizing that is irrelevant as I see it

Comment: [_My discussion of the problem_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pagination-optimization/), plus a workaround.

Comment: The technique works _if_ you don't have to scan the entire table, but instead can use an index to "remember where you left off".